# easy way to do recursion on paper?

Tags: recursion

I am preparing for computer science AP exam and have recursions as one of the topics. Being reletively new to programming I wanted to know if there is any easy way, or a few tips you would like to offer regarding recursion. On the exam we have no access to the computer (obviously). So what is an easy way to find solutions to recursions. For example the following is a problem diectly from my book.

```
public static int mystrey(int x)
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    } 
    else
    {
        return (x + mystrey(x/10)+mystrey(x/4);
    }
}
```

What would be the return value if mystrey(10) is called?

Comment: I think you'd benefit more from hard work than from shortcuts anyone could give you.

Comment: Yes my friend I have been working hard for the past 3 and a half months...I have gotten from the point of not knowing anything to this so...

Comment: @madth3: I don't think hard working on recursion learns you anything. It's like solving a rubiks cube. I know plenty of people who solve those cubes algorithmical, but they haven't got any insight in how it works. Persons who solve it without an algorithm know why if you turn it this way, you can for instance make a green plane. It's just by looking for solutions one begins to understand the power of recursion. I think there is a statement in computer science that is widly supported: "A good programmer is a lazy one."

Comment: @CommuSoft: The rubiks cube analogy is nice. Do you know how the speedcubers solve their cubes so fast? They memorize thousands and thousands of cases. Sort of like the problem-based educational system in the United States. Laziness is the new hard work.

Comment: Ok I'm not talking about speedcubers. I solve a rubics cube myself with insight. And furthermore the memorizing is a nice analogy to "dispatching" in my answer below :D. I only want to state that you don't improve programming skills by just imitating a computer. If this would be true, computers themselves would be the best programmers. I'm doing a project in Robotics, one of the fundamental thinks they want robotics to do is write there own programs. After 50 years of research it's still not done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you use recursion it's good to know the meaning of the function. This helps a lot to understand why the method is recursive. Furthermore calculating the function on paper is mostly done by a method called "dispatching". In this case you see that `mystrey(0) = 0` (the if-case).

If you want to calculate the value of mystrey(10) you know it's a sum of 10, mystrey(1) and mystrey(2).

You simply create a table where one can put:

```
0: 0
10: 10+f(1)+f(2)
```

we now calculate the value of the function with the highest argument so mystrey(2):

```
2: 2+f(0)+f(0)
```

we know the value of f(0), it's already in the table, so

```
2: 2+0+0=2
```

now we calculate `f(1)=1`

We finally conclude that `f(10)=10+f(1)+f(2)=10+1+2=13`.

Using a table becomes helpfull when there is a lot of recursion. A lot of times recursion results in overlap, where a huge number of times the function with the same arguments must be computed. With dispatching one can avoid the "branching". One can see recursion as a tree. Because `f(0)` has a fixed value this is called the "base case" and are the leafs of the tree. The other function values are called "branches". When calculating `f(10)` we need to calculate `f(1)` and `f(2)`, so one could draw edges from `f(10)` to `f(2)` and `f(1)`. And so one could repeat the process.

Also in most cases a good programmer will program this dispatching in the algorithm. This is of course done by declaring an array an store values in the array and perform a lookup on it.

In recursion theory it's common the recursion consist of two parts: a base case part, where answers are "hard coded" for some function calls (in your example when `x=0`), and a recursive part where `f(x)` is written in parts of `f(y)`. In general one can use dispatching by building an intial table with the hard coded values, and calculate the value of a specific `x` by starting to fill in the entry of `x` in the table, and work down.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is a *pain* to unroll manually. Basically, you substitute each recursive call with its output:

```
  mystrey(10)
= 10 + mystrey(10/10) + mystrey(10/4)
= 10 + (1 + mystrey(1/10) + mystrey(1/4)) + (5/2 + mystrey(5/20) + mystrey(5/8))
= ...
```

Since you declared the variables to be `int` types, everything smaller than `1` is mapped to `0`. Your `if (x == 0)` case returns `0` if `x == 0`, so you can conclude:

```
  mystrey(10)
= 10 + (1 + mystrey(1/10) + mystrey(1/4)) + (5/2 + mystrey(5/20) + mystrey(5/8))
= 10 + (1 + mystrey(0) + mystrey(0)) + (5/2 + mystrey(0) + mystrey(0))
= 10 + (1 + 0 + 0) + (5/2 + 0 + 0)
= 11 + 5/2
```

`5/2` is evaluated to `2`, so your final answer is `13` (I checked by running your code in Python).

Answer (score 2):

`mystrey(10)` executes the method body until `return (10 +` and then calls `mystrey(10/10)` recursively. That means, the computation of `x + mystrey(x/10)` has to wait until `mystrey(10/10)` returns a result.

So, `mystrey(1)` is computed and, in the same manner, returns `(1 + mystrey(0) + myStrey(0))`, which equals 1. Now we have `10 + 1 + mystrey(10/4)` in the initial outer method call.

I guess you have enough information to do the rest now.